# JavaScript puzzle to solve : window.confirm = divConfirm(strMessage)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax

Scenario is : old site which has lots of JS code already written. If user want to change all the alert messages to new age jazzy Div based alert which are very common using JQuery, YUI, Prototype... etc.  
There are mainly tree JS dialogs   
**1. alert**

To changes this its simple we just have to write new function which will show the div popup and show the message, after that override the window.alert  
  

`function showDivAlert(strMessage){ 

//div popup logic and code 

} 

 

window.alert = showDivAlert;`

**2. prompt**

This too look easy to write function to accept the string and show the text box for input value. Now as return action is based on the click of "OK" button life is easy here.

`function shoDivPromp(strMessage){ 

//div pop up to show the text box and accept input from the user 

} 

window.prompt = shoDivPromp;`

**3. confirm**

Now above two were easy to override and modify the default dialogs but there is complication with the confirm.
However default JS confirm dialog stops JS execution and when user click OK or Cancel execution is resumed by determining the return value (true/false). But if we user div popup the execution is not stopped which is problem.
 We can still implement the confirm but in that case we have to bind methods for OK and CANCEL case which will be attached to OK and CANCEL button. With this function signature will be like.
`function newConfirm(msg, fun OkAction(), fun CancelAction)`
Now this is problem that this cant help me change the confirm dialog across the site as we did with alert();
**Question**
I am not sure whether its possible or not to achieve but i think can be using some JS pattern. So let me know if its possible.

Comment: I don't understand how you can solve prompt but not confirm. How do you get to input value of the prompt call?

Comment: O i think u are right i missed the point, problem about confirm as its synchronous also exist for prompt dialog too ...... sorry about this i missed this while thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now this is problem that this cant help me change the confirm dialog across the site as we did with alert();

That's correct. It's not possible to reproduce the synchronous nature of the alert/confirm/prompt functions in native JavaScript. There is the non-standard method `showModalDialog` which can do it using a separate pop-up document, but it's not supported by all browsers and it's generally considered highly undesirable.

So the plug-in-replacement strategy isn't going to work. You are going to have to change every place you called these methods in the rest of the script.

The usual pattern is to do it using inline anonymous functions, to preserve the local variables using a closure, eg. replace:

```
function buttonclick() {
    var id= this.id;
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to frob '+id+'?'))
        frob(id);
    wipe(id);
}
```

with:

```
function buttonclick() {
    var id= this.id;
    myConfirm('Are you sure you want to frob '+id+'?', function(confirmed) {
        if (confirmed)
            frob(id);
        wipe(id);
    });
}
```

If you need `this` to be preserved you would need to look at a further nested closure or function.bind to do it. If you have your call to `confirm` in a loop things get considerably more difficult.

Obviously you also have to ensure that critical global state doesn't change whilst the confirm box is up. Usually this risk is minimised by greying out the rest of the page with an overlay to stop clicks getting through. However if you have timeouts they can still fire.

Comment: +1, I think part of bringing old sites like this up to date is removing the synchronous nature of modal boxes and getting as much of it as you can working asynchronously.  Nobody appreciates modal popups on web pages.

Answer (score 3):

All 3 methods actually stop js execution, not just the confirm, because they're all modal dialogs.  Personally, I would try to keep everything as asynchronous as possible as modal dialogs prevent interaction with the current document.

Your best bet is to use callback functions from the new confirm popup as you suggested yourself.

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you want to achieve.  It sounds like you want to do something like the following:

- Run some javascript code
- Display a "confirm" box
- Wait until the ok button or cancel button is clicked
- Continue code when user clicks ok, return when user clicks cancel.

The reason you want to do this is that overriding the function with something that makes use of callbacks would require rewriting each section of code that uses the confirm function.  If you want my advice, I would go ahead and rewrite the code so that it performs asynchronously.  There's no way you can delay script execution without locking up the document which includes the OK and Cancel actions of your dialog.

Answer (score 2):

if you changed the roles Alert / Prompt / Confirm. slows the execution pending user interaction to run the following code.

Overriding these functions, the code continues its execution.

To achieve this you have to modify each part of the code and work as if you were with asynchronous functions.

Then you can use any plugin for windows as [sexy-alert-box](http://www.coders.me/ejemplos/sexy-alert-box-1-2/), and overwrite Alert / Prompt / Confirm

Answer (score 1):

The function signature would simply be:

```
 function newConfirm(msg, okAction, cancelAction);
```

and would be used as:

```
 function newConfirm(msg, okAction, cancelAction){
   var ok = doWhateverPromptIsNecessary();
   if (ok) {
     okAction();
   } else {
     cancelAction();
   }
 }
```

That is, to pass function "pointers" in to a function as arguments, simply pass in the function name without the (). The function signature is the same.

Comment: yes you are correct but i am looking for some magical pattern which can do that inside the function body. Which only can help me override the window.confirm = confirm(str) dialog. Only problem with above is that i have to change calls for all the confim which are used already in code.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible, as others have indicated.