# can I override/redefine "global" Javascript functions, like confirm() and alert()?

Tags: javascript, confirm, browser-automation

I want to do some browser automation, and those pesky confirm/alert boxes are a real pain. Disabling javascript completely in this case is not an option, unfortunately.

Well, so I was wondering, can I just change the definition of those methods as seen by my browser's javascript interpreter to basically do nothing and return true? Note that I do know about redefining them in the Javascript code directly, e.g. putting in

```
function alert(message)
{
  return true;
}
```

but AFAIK this is not a viable approach for this situation because when doing browser automation I have to work with other people's Javascript. Moreover, my program actually begins manipulating these websites already after the page has fully loaded into the browser, so I cannot just first automatically rewrite the javascript and then load the page. Well, so I was wondering if I could instead just "permanently" modify the way alert/confirm are implemented and executed in my browser. Sort of like the equivalent of dll injection and so forth in the realm of windows apps.

Comment: What browser are you automating? eg. for Firefox GreaseMonkey would be a way to inject function-replacement code into each page.

Comment: it's Internet Explorer - the browser control placed on a Windows app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done. Try this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056747/javascript-puzzle-to-solve-window-confirm-divconfirmstrmessage)

Comment: I have already mentioned this approach in my original post. It doesn't work because I am not the guy running the server and I cannot insert new code into the Javascript files from the server. I am the guy doing browser automation, and my browser ends up loading whatever javascript provided by the website.

Answer (score 0):

this work on chrome 10, ff 4, msie 8 (using jquery for brevity)

```
window.alert = function(x) {
    $('<pre>',{text:x}).appendTo('body');
    }
```