# confirm box customized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i  need a green color confirm box along with yes no button instead of ok/cancel . Can u please suggest how i can achieve this.. if there is an alternative please give me the code for it including the css and jquery, javascript files needed to run it. I am a novice in web field so your help will be highly appreciated..thanks.

Comment: I suggest to use a javascript framework like jQuery. They offer several ways to build dialog boxes and customize them. ex: http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: Just as a note, I use tooltips instead of modal dialogs. They seem cleaner.

Comment: This is the same question as your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498988/confirm-box-styling). The answers already provide a good starting point - do not expect people to do your work for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056747/javascript-puzzle-to-solve-window-confirm-divconfirmstrmessage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [jQuery Plugin Confirm Box: jDialog](http://kailashnadh.name/code/jqdialog/).  You can basically skin it the way you like with CSS.  Or, you can use [jQuery UI's modal box](http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/dialog/#default)

Comment: thank u so much... jqdialog really did the trick..

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/)
it's really easy to be done!