# Pointer cursor of buttons in confirm box

Tags: javascript

When I am using a javascript confirm like below:

```
         function showConfirm(){

     var confirmMsg=confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards your Session." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" );
```

}

How can I display a pointer cursor over the OK and Cancel button?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I display a pointer cursor over the OK and Cancel button?

You can't. How the confirm box is rendered and what cursors are used, is entirely up to the browser.

If you want that kind of control, you'll need to use a [custom confirm dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499805/confirm-box-customized) - note however that those require that you change the way your code works, using callback functions to catch the "OK" or "Cancel" click events.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info I will not bother with the pointer cursor then.