# ios "web control" alert() dialog showing HTML local storage Folder name in Title

Tags: html, ios, alert, web-controls, confirm

we are beuilding an iOS application that uses the internal web control to render locally stored HTML pages. We have found that when the HTML page invokes alert(), prompt() or confirm() that the dialog opens but has the name of the folder that the page is stored in for the title. Obviously this looks like gibberish. I am assuming that it sees the folder as the "host server".

Example
In Safari web browser : Message From Web Browser
In iOS Application using web control: 475b7e1b6004451da78b33b5194f386d

I have been prototyping and following threads on here to overwrite the dialog with my own HTML  with a custom CSS, however this, as I understand, means that we will have to rewrite the confirm() behaviour with our own functions. I was wondering if anyone could point me in a direction within xCode to publish a generic statement rather than the folder name?

One of the sites I have used:
[JavaScript puzzle to solve : window.confirm = divConfirm(strMessage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056747/javascript-puzzle-to-solve-window-confirm-divconfirmstrmessage)

Thanks in advance.