# How can I replace window.onbeforeunload with custom code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For accessibility reasons, for my Chrome extension, I need to be able to replace all standard `window.onbeforeunload` popups with an in-page HTML substitute. I know how to create a substitute skeleton, that's trivial.

And I know the basic idea here is `window.onbeforeunload = {my substitute code}`.

What I don't know how to do is grab the text and code from each confirmation window that a page issues, and channel it into my substitute, so that the same message is shown as would be in the original popup and clicking my substitute `confirm` and `leave page` (or whatever) buttons yield the same result as the original popup.

How can this be done?

---

EXAMPLE:

You have my extension installed (don't ask what its purpose is, irrelevant).

You start writing a question on StackOverflow, then realize you already know the answer and go to close the tab.

Normally, a confirmation window would come up asking if you're sure you want to leave the page.

But because of my extension, instead, the whole page's HTML gets shoved down a bit to make room for a temporary HTML confirmation box is shown with the same text and the same two buttons that yield the same two results when clicked, all in-page. No pop-up.

Comment: That's not `window.confirm()`; that's the browser's `beforeunload` handler.  I don't think you can easily override that.

Comment: Hmm...this is problematic.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056747/javascript-puzzle-to-solve-window-confirm-divconfirmstrmessage

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @putvande voice control.

Comment: @SLaks I edited the question to match your info, which was something I didn't realize. The question still stands though-- as I noted in my comment below Robert Byrne's answer, it seems you can replace the code altogether and prevent the popup. The question, though, is still how can you get at the popup's message and the code executed by its buttons.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you're talking about is the `window.onbeforeunload` event, and unfortunately the only way it can be customized is to provide a custom string message for the user, because the potential for abuse is so high.

The api reference over at msdn for [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states:

> The default statement that appears in the dialog box, "Are you sure
>   you want to navigate away from this page? ... Press OK to continue, or
>   Cancel to stay on the current page.", cannot be removed or altered.

I take this to mean the **dialog** itself cannot be altered, all you can do is provide an additional context-specific message. I cant locate the same reference for Chrome, but it seems to be the same story there.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    //all you can do is provide a message..
    return "you have unsaved changes, if you leave they will be lost";
}
```

Comment: There *must* be some way to programmatically deal with this.

Comment: You could try capture links, form submissions etc, and prevent navigation before showing your custom UI, but there's nothing to stop the user from just closing the window. The only reliable event I've found cross-browser is this one, but it is quite limited alas

Comment: ACTUALLY...not sure if this is a solution yet because I haven't gone through it mentally, but stealing the final code snippet from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/419881/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Stopping-onbeforeunload-event) and sticking it in the console did indeed prevent the `onbeforeunload` popup from firing.

Comment: But will that prevent the page from navigating away? do you actually just want to prevent the message from appearing at all?

Comment: What I'm building is an extension that allows *total* voice control of chrome. I need to be able to programmatically deal with all popups, including this one, since the extension's purpose is to prevent the user from needing to hit any keys. So I need to be able to present the user with the message and let them deal with it by voice rather than by mouse or keyboard, which involves a bit of reconfiguration.

Comment: Ah I understand, and you can not interface with the actual Chrome application, just the hosted web page? The only other thing that comes to mind is something like Selenium Web Driver, which can be scripted and deals with native dialogs